# iPhone OpenGL ES texture unit

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures

I am new to writing OpenGL ES for the iPhone. I am trying to render yuv texture, but am very confused by the concept of a texture unit.

If I change the glUniform1i's second parameter with different combination, the resulting image is different. My question is how is this 0 or 1 texture unit configured? What is the right way of using it?

Edit:
Stupid me... forgot to call this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a texture to an available texture unit using code like the following:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
```

This assumes you've properly configured both `texture1` and `texture2`, of course.

When it comes time to bind your textures to your shaders, you specify which texture unit that particular texture is bound to using code like the following:

```
glUniform1i(texture1Index, 0);
glUniform1i(texture2Index, 1);
```

where `texture1Index` and `texture2Index` are the indices of the appropriate uniforms for your shader.  The 0 and 1 correspond to the texture units we bound the textures to earlier on.