# Hardcoding GLSL texture sampler2D

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

In my fragment shader, I have the line

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, destinationTextureCoordinate) * destinationColor;
```

Where `texture` is a uniform of type `sampler2D`. In my code , I always set this to the value '0'.

```
glUniform1i(_uniformTexture, 0);
```

Is it possible to skip the call to `glUniform1i` and just hardcore 0 in the fragment shader? I tried just replacing `texture` with `0` and it complained about not being a valid type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but here are some thoughts:

`sampler2D` needs to sample a 2D texture, as the name indicates. It is a special GLSL variable, so the compiler is right to complain about `0` not being a valid type when fed into the first parameter of `texture2D`.

Unless you are using multiple textures, the second parameter to `glUniform1i` should always be `0` (default). You can skip this call if you are only using a single texture, but it's good practice to leave it in.

Why do you need a call to texture2D if you just want to pass the value 0? Surely you can just do `gl_FragColor = destinationColor`. This will color your fragment based on the vertex shader output from `gl_Position`. I'm not sure why you are implementing a texture if you don't plan on using it (or so it seems).

EDIT: Code to send two textures to the fragment shader correctly.

```
//glClear();

// Attach Texture 0
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture0);
glUniform1i(_uSampler0, 0);

// Attach Texture 1
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture1);
glUniform1i(_uSampler1, 1);

//glDrawArrays();
```

Comment: I intend on only ever using a single texture at a time. The rationale behind replacing `texture` with `0` is that `_uniformTexture` is the position of `texture`, and the value at the position `_uniformTexture` is set to `0` (via the call to `glUniform1i`). Not sure why this isn't more obvious.

I also tried replacing `texture` with `(sampler2D)0`, that too didn't work.

Comment: `_uniformTexture` is just a handle to the `sampler2D` variable in your shader. When you send `0` via the call to `glUniform1i` you are really just telling the sampler where to sample from, given an active and bound texture (see code edit above). A value of 0 here doesn't mean "sample nothing", it means sample from stage index 0.

What is your texture being used for exactly? I don't see a benefit in setting it to 0.

Comment: Seems like it, happy coding!

Comment: Just for clarification - this means the sampler2D in GLSL always corresponds to whatever glActiveTexture was used to bind a texture and never to the texture handle ("_texture1" in your example). In OpenGL you can bind 1D/2D/3D textures at the same time under a single glActiveTexture() - I assume this is not allowed/working within GLSL? (I couldn't get it to work, at least)

Comment: I'm not very experienced with OpenGL, so I can't comment on the API differences. However, [Brad Larson's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366033/iphone-opengl-es-texture-unit) might be the best explanation available for you. My code excerpt above follows the same style and reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

You need a **layout**, like this:

```
#version 420
//#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack: enable  Use for GLSL versions before 420.

layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D diffuseTex;
```

In that way you are getting a binding to the **sampler uniform 0**. I think that is what you want. But keep in mind that when you are binding uniforms they got incremental values from zero, so be sure what you want to bind. The idea to bind uniform variables via the `glUniform1i()` function is to ensure the correctness of your code.

Source: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Version_4.20_binding